# spring mvc exception handler with @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC application I have a number of methods that use `@RequestBody` to bind to domain objects I've defined (specifically, from JSON using Jackson).

I'm currently using a simple view for exceptions as follows:

```
<bean id="exceptionHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="errorXmlView" />
</bean>


<bean id="errorXmlView" class="com.example.MyCustomXmlView" />
```

My question is, inside `MyCustomXmlView`, which currently just extends `AbstractView`, is there a way I can get access to the object that was bound with `@RequestBody`? Assuming, that is, that it got that far and it wasn't a binding exception. For example, is there some kind of request-scoped bean I could call upon, or a way to get the object injected into the model for my exception view? If not, is there a different way of defining an exception resolver that *would* allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often times capture controller method parameters with a `ThreadLocal`, and then store them for later use in logging, etc. The best way I've found is to use an `@Aspect` (or whatever AOP strategy you prefer) to intercept the controller methods and store the method parameters for later use.

Comment: That sounds promising. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I didn't end up doing precisely this, because I realized capturing the object wasn't quite what I wanted (I wanted the raw JSON), but this set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the [`@ExceptionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation?  The [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) has an example of its usage, and I imagine you can create a custom exception that will hold onto your model, which you should then be able to access in your exception handling method.

Comment: I'll take a look, but at first glance I don't see how an `@ExceptionHandler` method would get access to the object that was bound by `@RequestBody` in the original controller method. I can't read the body of the raw `HttpServletRequest` because that's already been done.

Comment: Or are you saying in each of my controllers I need to myself put that object somewhere? The point is I'm trying to catch all kinds of exceptions, from NullPointerException to DataAccessException.

Comment: @Dan Perhaps I understood you incorrectly.  Do you want to know, in the place that will be doing the error handling, what the object was that came in from the request?

Comment: that's right. I'm just trying to include as much information as I can in my error reporting, with some reasonable limits.